# javascript function bug after a correct condition

Tags: javascript

i have finished the code of the popular snake game, it runs perfectly.
then i decided to add a level 2, so i put a condition that after the apples eaten by the snake become 10, there will be a level up and we will pass to level 2.
in level 2 there are 2 new lines drawn on the board, with the condition that if the snake hit these lines, the game will be over ( same for borders and the snake body )
here is the code:

here, game = setInterval(draw, gameSpeed), where gamespeed is the time in milliseconds and draw is the function that draws everything on the canvas

```
if(apples_eaten == 10){

    clearInterval(game); 
    levelUp();
}
```

here is the levelup() function that should only run once in the whole game as there are only 2 levels.

```
function levelUp() {

lvl = 2;
apples_eaten = 0;

let display_lvl = document.getElementById("level");
display_lvl.innerHTML = "level: " + lvl;

snake.length = 1;
snake[0] = {
    x : 15 * unit,
    y : 10  * unit
};

apple = {
    x : generate(1, w/unit),
    y : generate(1, h/unit),
    color : "red"
};

gameSpeed = 70;

game = setInterval(draw, gameSpeed);
```

}

the problem is that after reaching level 2, the game still runs correctly, except that if the snake eat a single apple, it starts bugging, moving in every direction and throwing the "you hit something" alert, that normally is thrown when you hit a border, line or itself

Comment: `clearInterval(game); ` check if game is a valid handle or if its stuck within a local scope.

Comment: i made this variable global ( without var or let ) and still not working

Comment: Chances are there is another loop you're forgetting to stop so both run at the same time giving you conflicting results.

Comment: im clearing this interval before anything when in a condition, then i rewrite a new one.

Comment: like the example above, i cleared it in the condition if apples == 10, then rewrite a new one at the end of the code in the levelup function

Comment: Did you try to reset the `apples_eaten` variable to 0 within the condition, when calling the levelUp function), rather than in the function?

Comment: yes i did, still no changes